# Simple links between UI objects in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I simply want to link a label to a slider in order for it to display the current value of that slider. This is my first time working with Objective-C, and the problem seems far more complicated than in Java or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first thing you will see demonstrated in the [Stanford CS193P videos on iTunes](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225) - if you want to do it in Interface Builder look no further.